# Can I manage my contacts from inside Geary?

Tags: pantheon-mail

Does Geary come with any contact management? I'd like to create and maintain mailing lists and contacts. Does this feature exist somewhere in Geary?

Comment: Might not be that helpful as you ask for a contact list IN Geary, but there is the external Contacts (gnome-contacts). https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Contacts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Geary does not have a contact management interface, but it does store contacts for auto-completion. These contacts are pulled from the emails that it has downloaded.

There are long-term goals for Geary to integrate into a system-wide contacts database (so a separate Contacts app could be used), but this is not yet implemented.

---

Source: [Re: [Geary] How does Geary get my Google contacts?](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/geary-list/2014-July/msg00023.html)